# Reference a style without "@" symbol?

Tags: android, xml, styles

i have this code:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_color</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MiwokAppBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <!-- App bar style -->
    <style name="MiwokAppBarStyle" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <!-- Remove the shadow below the app bar -->
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Style for a tab that displays a category name -->
    <style name="CategoryTab" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/CategoryTabTextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Text appearance style for a category tab -->
    <style name="CategoryTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textColor">#A8A19E</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

why in `MiwokAppBarStyle` we don't use `@` symbol in referencing the parent style like this  `parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse"` ?, and why we referencing parent style using `style/` insted of referencing without `style/` prefix like `parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse"` ??